# How to get JSON data from a url and place markers on Google Maps?

Tags: android, json, google-maps, coordinates, marker

I wanted to know how I can get JSON data from a URL and add the coordinates (lat, long) as markers into Google Maps in android studio(3.1.1).

I cannot figure out how to do this.

Link: https://opendata.brussels.be/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=parkings

Comment: post what you've tried so far otherwise no one will write your code for you.. you can use libraries to query the url and parse the response.. if you face problem then post well detailed questions

Comment: Used Retrofit to easy to handle json data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with this code

```
JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonArr = jsonobj.getJSONArray(jsonobj.getString("records"));
```

for further information check this out

https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you, I followed the tutorial and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

**dropMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_drop)).position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).draggable(false));**